# session create / read / problems when login

Tags: php, session

i want to create seassion some values like;

**My session Functions ;**

```
## QUERY ##
function query($sql){
    return mysql_query($sql);
}
function result($sql){
    return mysql_fetch_array($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
function results($sql){
    return mysql_num_rows($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}    
    function p($par, $st = false) {
        if ($st) {
            return htmlspecialchars(addslashes(trim($_POST[$par])));
        } else {
            return addslashes(trim($_POST[$par]));
        }
    }
    ## SESSIONS ##
    function session_create($par) {
        foreach ($par as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    function session($par){
        if ($_SESSION[$par]) {
            return $_SESSION[$par];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Controls ;**

```
<?php 
    if (session('login') && session('user_type') == 1) {
        require_once 'inc/default.php';
    } else {
        require_once 'inc/login.php';
    }
?>
```

**Login file.**

```
    <?php 
        if ($_POST) {
            $kullaniciadi = p('kullaniciadi');
            $sifre = md5(p('sifre'));
            if ($kullaniciadi == '' || $sifre == '') {
                echo '<span class="error">Kullanıcı adı ve / veya şifre boş bırakılamaz.</span><div class="clearfix"></div><br />';
            } else {
                $sql = query("SELECT * FROM cms_uyeler WHERE 
                    user_username ='$kullaniciadi' && 
                    user_password ='$sifre' && 
                    user_type= 1");
                if (mysql_affected_rows()) {
                    $result = results($sql);
                    $session =  array (
                        'login' => true,
                        'user_id' => $result['user_id'],
                        'user_type' => $result['user_type'],
                        'user_username' => $result['user_username'],
                        );
                    session_create($session);
                    go(SITEURL.'/admin');

                } else {
                    echo '<span class="error">Bu kullanıcı yetkileri uygun değil.</span><div class="clearfix"></div><br />';
                }
            }
    } ?>
```

The problem is, when i print the SESSION the print value like this;

```
Array ( [login] => 1 [user_id] => [user_type] => [user_username] => )
```

I dont know whats should i do ?
Where i am wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: add `session_start()`  in the top of the page `<?php session_start()`

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers i did. i started the session in top of the inc/settings.php http://prntscr.com/35iysr

Comment: That is some truly terrible code...

Comment: i see you need to move the session_start() to the current page , if its works then you have Php headers issue you need to fix your code using ob_start()

Comment: i did it also like http://prntscr.com/35j05w @NinjaDevelopers

Comment: @kralyk i really new about this. by the way -NinjaDevelopers is there any problem about session_create() function ?

Comment: wired , have you tried to add `session_start()` at the current page ? this is really wired try to save settings.php as `utf8 withoutbom`

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers i tried but didint work again  :/

Comment: my advice to you is to use 1 `session` variable as `array` and save inside it the `session` `variables` , this would be nice and don't forget to `serialize` the array when you set the session

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers `$session =  array (` variable make what u say :/

Comment: Noooo I mean `$_SESSION['userinfo'] = array();` , `$_SESSION['userinfo'] ['username'] = 'blaa'`

Comment: omg. my functions are sucks. i ix the problem work with mysqli db class. thanks for your help.